# Update Emoji font on older Mac OS?

Tags: macos, fonts, osx-yosemite, ios

I'm using OS X Yosemite, which I don't want to update to the latest due to compatibility and performance issues.   But I want to update the emoji font used by Messages to match the latest iOS.

Questions are:

- How to get the newer emoji font?
- How to install it on OS X Yosemite?

Thanks!